# Gradle: Changing configuration of external dependency

Tags: java, gradle

We're in the situation where we update commons-collections from version 3 to version 4. As they've changed the group id to commons-collections4 we will end up having 2 versions of commons-collection in the classpath. The version 3 and version 4. 
For our development the version 4 should be used. The version 3 will come in through external dependencies so if we have like:

```
compile ("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.5.6-Final")
```

the version 3, which will come in through hibernate-entitymanager, will also be available at compile time. So the developers could use it.

Is there a way to say "commons-collections 3 should now be considered as runtime dependency when it comes through hibernate-entitymanager"?

We're using Gradle 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to webdizz who brings me to that idea it seems that I managed it by doing the following:

```
configurations.compileClasspath.resolutionStrategy {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('commons-collections:commons-collections') with module("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:${COMMONS_COLLECTIONS_VERSION}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a proper way exist to achieve this, however what if you force all version of `commons3` to be replaced with `commons4` at `compile` configuration, and additionally define a `runtime` only annotation?

```
configurations.compile {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'commons4',
}

dependencies {
    runtime('commons3')
}
```

Comment: This could work. I guess gradle won't provide a nicer way for this case. I'll give it a try tomorrow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/2.2.1/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:module_replacement) where they use `replacedBy` to tell gradle that `com.google.collections:google-collections` was replaced by `com.google.guava:guava`. Gradle will now consider the two modules as a single module in dependency resolution and will never include both.

```
dependencies {
    modules {
        module("com.google.collections:google-collections") {
            replacedBy("com.google.guava:guava")
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want to archive. We need to have both in the classpath. commons-collections also changed their package structure so the external dependencies which work with version 3 still need to have the version 3 in place. E.g. in Version 3 MapUtils was in package import org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils in version 4 it's in import org.apache.commons.collections4.MapUtils. Therefore I can't just replace it.